# Automatically tuning the batch size by catching out of memory errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like my application to automatically find the maximum batch size possible so I set up a binary search that catches OOM exceptions like this:

```py
min_batch_size = 3072
max_batch_size = 16384
min_range = 512  # Exit when the search range is smaller than this.
sample_iterations = 5
while max_batch_size - min_batch_size > min_range:
  batch_size = (max_batch_size + min_batch_size) // 2
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    train_op = build_graph()
    try:
      with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
        for _ in range(sample_iterations):
          sess.run(train_op)
    except tf.errors.ResourceExhaustedError:
      max_batch_size = batch_size
    else:
      min_batch_size = batch_size
return min_batch_size
```

Using the official TensorFlow 1.12 Docker image, it starts to converge to the actual batch size discarding sizes that are too large to fit on the current hardware. However, it fails on this internal error at the 6th iteration:

```
  File "opennmt/runner.py", line 252, in _auto_tune_batch_size
    with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=session_config) as sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1551, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 676, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

What is the cause of this error, given the process I described above? Are OOM errors generally not safe to recover from? How can I work around it to achieve my initial goal **within the application and not by running scripts**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it as a separate script that writes the final batch size to a file.

After the script ends, I think the GPU would reset properly and you could read that file to get the desired batch size.